# ERROR: relation "shemaname.trame" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create FUNCTION to delete from all schemas in the table trame the data + 6 month

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleteTrame01 ()  
RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
declare

    shemaName TEXT;
BEGIN
 For shemaName IN  select schema_name  from information_schema.schemata where schema_name NOT LIKE 'public'
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'information_schema'
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_toast'
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_temp_1'
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_catalog'
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'template_schema' 
 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_toast_temp_1' LOOP
delete  from shemaName.trame where shemaName.trame.date < NOW() - INTERVAL '180 days' ;
  RETURN NEXT shemaName ;
END LOOP;
RETURN ;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**ERROR =>**

```
ERROR:  relation "shemaname.trame" does not exist
LINE 1: delete  from shemaName.trame where shemaName.trame.date < NO...
                     ^
QUERY:  delete  from shemaName.trame where shemaName.trame.date < NOW() - INTERVAL '180 days'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function deletetrame01() line 13 at SQL statement
```

********** Error **********

```
ERROR: relation "shemaname.trame" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function deletetrame01() line 13 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable as an identifier. you need to use dynamic SQL for that. This means building a string that contains the schema name that you retrieved through the loop. The recommended way to build a SQL string with identifiers is to use the [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function so that identifiers needing quotes are properly handled.

The loop variable of a "select loop" also needs to be a record, not a scalar value - even if you only select a single column.

And finally I would use `information_schema.tables` and include a condition on the table name, just to make sure you are not including a schema where that table doesn't exist. The multiple NOT LIKE conditions without a wildcard can be replaced with a single NOT IN condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleteTrame01 ()  
RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
declare
   l_rec record
BEGIN
  For l_rec IN  select schema_name
                from information_schema.tables
                where table_name = 'trame' --<< only include schemas that do have that table
                 and schema_name NOT IN ('public', 
                                         'information_schema', 
                                         'pg_catalog', 
                                         'template_schema' )
                 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_toast%'
                 and schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_temp%'
  LOOP
    execute format('delete from %I.trame where "date" < NOW() - INTERVAL ''180 days'', l_rec.schema_name) ;
    RETURN NEXT l_rec.shemaName;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```